# Beginning C++ - Decimal Place Issue

Tags: c++, decimal

I am learning how to use C++ and would appreciate help in solving a problem I have.  This is the first program I have written, it calculates numbers of calories burned and distance needed to burn the calories off.  Everything seems fine, my only issue is the output 'total_calories' does not show decimal places. I want it to display 1775.00 instead of 1775.  My input values are burgers_consumed = 3, fries_consumed = 1 , and drinks_consumed = 2.

The output that I get is:
 You ingested 1775 calories. 
 You will have to run 4.73 miles to expend that much energy.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int BURGER_CALORIES = 400;
    const int FRIES_CALORIES = 275;
    const int SOFTDRINK_CALORIES = 150;
    double burgers_consumed;
    double fries_consumed;
    double drinks_consumed;
    double total_calories;
    double total_distance;


    //Get the number of hamburgers consumed.
    cout << " How many hamburgers were consumed? ";
    cin >>  burgers_consumed;

    //Get the number of fries consumed.
    cout << " How many french fries were consumed? ";
    cin >> fries_consumed;

    //Get the number of drinks consumed.
    cout << " How many soft drinks were consumed? ";
    cin >> drinks_consumed;

    //Calculate the total calories consumed.
    total_calories = (BURGER_CALORIES * burgers_consumed) + (FRIES_CALORIES * fries_consumed) + (SOFTDRINK_CALORIES * drinks_consumed);

    //Calculate total distance needed to burn of calories consumed.
    total_distance = total_calories/375;

    //Display number of calories ingested.
   cout.precision(6);
    cout << " You ingested " << total_calories << " calories. " << endl;

    //Display distance needed to burn off calories.
   cout.precision(3);
    cout << " You will have to run " << total_distance << " miles to expend that much energy. " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to  set `ios::fixed` flag in order to always see trailing zeroes.

```
cout << " You ingested " << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << total_calories << " calories. " << endl;
```

From  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/:

> When floatfield is set to fixed, floating-point values are written using fixed-point notation: the value is represented with exactly as many digits in the decimal part as specified by the precision field (precision) and with no exponent part.

As BobbyDigital noted, you may just want to set this setting at the beginning of your program, as these settings are persistent:

```
 cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed);
```

Don't forget also to set the precision!

Comment: Could be noted that such settings are persistent and can be set once until a change is needed. I have a simple `setMoney()` function to use in financial apps.

Comment: Yes, I will add that in my answer! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Nemanja as well as BobbyD, I appreciate your help and the link. I was going crazy trying to figure this out, the output is correct now.